# Problems trying to connect to local database with pgadmin4

Tags: python, backend

I am new with backend and postgresql. I am trying to to set up on linux mint.

I have installed postgresql.

And set up pgadmin4 with python as instructed https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python/

After connecting to pgadmin4 and going to the local address with browser and logging in with proper username and password I get error message in terminal as follows

```
2023-06-15 13:56:58,016: WARNING    werkzeug:   WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.
 * Serving Flask app 'pgadmin'
 * Debug mode: off
2023-06-15 13:57:13,474: ERROR  pgadmin:    Exception when checking for update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1348, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1447, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 941, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 845, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 833, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omistaja/pgadmin4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/browser/__init__.py", line 433, in check_browser_upgrade
    response = urlopen(url, data, 5)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1391, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
```

The pgamin opens browser and there is one "Server" but nothing inside it.
(Not sure if this helps with anything but if I try to create new servers they are empty)

How can I address this? Or can you recommend better alternatives to pgadmin for linux mint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you received indicates a timeout while checking for updates in pgAdmin. This error should not affect the functionality of pgAdmin or your PostgreSQL database. Here are some steps to address the issue:

*Disable automatic update checks in the pgAdmin configuration file.
*Check your network connectivity to ensure a stable internet connection.
*Try using a different browser to access pgAdmin's web interface.
*Verify the connection to your PostgreSQL server in pgAdmin.

If the issue persists, you can try alternative PostgreSQL administration tools like DBeaver or Adminer. Another option is to use the command-line tool called psql.

Remember, the timeout error should not significantly impact your ability to work with PostgreSQL. You can try the steps mentioned or explore alternative tools based on your preference.